# PHP Excel generating using zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, frameworks

When I am going to generate an EXCEL file using PHPExcel  class in zend framework I will get an error when data is more than 20 days ERROR IS

> File not found
>
> Firefox can't find the file at http://eyeq.local/eyeq/reports/reading-speed-analysis-report/op/export/organization_id/1/department_id//from_date/03-12-2013/to_date/04-01-2013/userType/1/user_id//reportSize/full.
>
> Check the file name for capitalization or other typing errors.
>     Check to see if the file was moved, renamed or deleted.

I have already increased execution time to 18000 and memory limit to 256m

Comment: Shouldn't `organization_id`, `department_id` and `user_id` be replaced with variables?

Answer (score 0):

The **department_id** is empty in the url

i.e. URL*...../department_id/**[THIS SHOULD BE AN INT]**/from_date......*